# How to render the append string to html using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs, next.js

here's the code:

```
const Gauge = (props) => {
    const points = 100;
    const radius = 257;
    const max = 100;
    const peaks = [ 10, 50, 90 ];
    const step = (max + 1) / points;
    const realPeaks = peaks.map((peak) => Math.floor(peak * (1 / step)));
    const hueStep = 120 / points;

    const digitContainer = useRef(null);
    const innerContainer = useRef(null);

const [digits, setDigits] = useState(props.item.temperature);
    useEffect(() => {
        digitContainer.current.append(`<span class="digit current-digit count">0</span>`);



for (let i = 0; i < points; i++) {
        const degree = i * (radius / (points - 1)) - radius / 2;
        const isPeak = realPeaks.indexOf(i) > -1;
        innerContainer.current.append(`<i className="bar${isPeak ? ' peak' : ''}" style="transform: rotate(${degree}deg)"></i>`);

        const intStep = Math.ceil(step * i);
        const intNextStep = Math.ceil(step * (i + 1));
    }
        console.log(digitContainer.current);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={style['gauge']} data-digit={digits}>
            <div ref={digitContainer}></div>
<div ref={innerContainer}></div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

What I'm trying to do here is to render the string `<span class="digit current-digit count">0</span>` to html code. cause when I try to console the digitContainer.current the value is string instead of html.

the output is like this:

```
<div className="gauge data-digit{digits}">
    <div>
      '<span class="digit current-digit count">0</span>'
    </div>
    <div>
    '<span>......</span>'
    '<span>......</span>'
    '<span>......</span>'
    '<span>......</span>'
    '<span>......</span>'
    '<span>......</span>'
    '<span>......</span>'
    </div>
    </div>
```

instead

```
<div className="gauge data-digit{digits}>
    <div>
      <span class="digit current-digit count">0</span>
    </div>
    <div>
    <span>......</span>
    <span>......</span>
    <span>......</span>
    <span>......</span>
    <span>......</span>
    <span>......</span>
    <span>......</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why would you do this rather than just including the `span` in the `div` in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65771416/how-to-render-html-string-as-real-html-using-react-w-out-component), I'm going to assume there's more to it than just the `span`.

You wouldn't use `useEffect` for this at all. Instead, you'd probably use an array and then use that array in the JSX at the end:

```
const Gauge = (props) => {
    const points = 100;
    const radius = 257;
    const max = 100;
    const peaks = [ 10, 50, 90 ];
    const step = (max + 1) / points;
    const realPeaks = peaks.map((peak) => Math.floor(peak * (1 / step)));
    const hueStep = 120 / points;

    // Build the array
    const digits = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < points; i++) {
        const degree = i * (radius / (points - 1)) - radius / 2;
        const isPeak = realPeaks.indexOf(i) > -1;
        digits.push(<i key={i} className={`bar${isPeak ? ' peak' : ''}`} style={{transform: `rotate(${degree}deg)`}}/>);
    }

    // Use it below
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
            <span key="count" class="digit current-digit count">0</span>
            {digits}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

I'm guessing your next step is doing things to those elements. If so, you probably would want to have an array in your state information containing the information for each `i` in the array, and render based on the current state of that array. In that situation, you'd probably (again) have the array in state and then use `map` when rendering:

```
const Gauge = (props) => {
    const points = 100;
    const radius = 257;
    const max = 100;
    const peaks = [ 10, 50, 90 ];
    const step = (max + 1) / points;
    const realPeaks = peaks.map((peak) => Math.floor(peak * (1 / step)));
    const hueStep = 120 / points;
    const [digits, setDigits] = useState([]);

    // ...things here to fill in `digits` via `setDigits` in response to
    // various things (perhaps an initial `useEffect` if loading them
    // from somewhere)...

    // Use it below
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
            <span key="count" class="digit current-digit count">{digits.length}</span>
            {digits.map(digit => <i key={digit.someUsefulKey} className={`bar${digit.isPeak ? " peak" : ""}`} style={{transform: `rotate(${degree}deg)`}}/>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

The key thing here is: Don't think in HTML/markup. Think in terms of state information, then *render* the state information as necessary.

---

Note the `key` property I've added to the `i` elements in the above. See [this page in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more about the `key` property. If you can use something more organic than just the index, that would be best, but I didn't see anything in this that could be used for that purpose.

Comment: is it ok that I will not use ```useEffect```?. for example I have 1 data then every 5 minutes it should update the information.

Comment: Well, this is indeed a better way

Comment: @BeginnerCoder - I've updated the answer. You only need `useEffect` if you need to do something after the component mounts and then (optionally) in response to something happening that isn't handled by an event handler.  Hopefully the above gets you headed the right direction. The key thing here is: Don't think in HTML/markup. Think in terms of state information, then *render* the state information as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render innerHTML

```
const innerHTML = '<span class="digit current-digit count">0</span>'
function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={innerHTML} />;
}
```

Comment: You *can*, but there's no good reason to here, and lots of good reasons *not* to.